# Visual Studio 2017 for Mac - mouse cursor does not appear where mouse is clicked

Tags: mouse, macbook, visual-studio

I have a brand new MacBook Pro with Mojave Version 10.14.3 in which I installed Visual Studio 2017.

When returning from lunch I unblocked the machine and for unknown reasons both the mouse pad and the USB mouse started acting strangely on Visual Studio ONLY.

Whenever I move the cursor with either pointing devices, when I click somewhere in the file I'm editing, the cursor appears seven lines below from where I clicked. If I click on a file in solution explorer the same thing happens, the file several lines below from where I clicked gets selected. If hoovering on top of the file I'm editing I move the cursor towards the menu, the text in the file gets selected.

I have tried closing and re-opening Visual Studio and even restarting the machine to no avail.

The mouse works fine in all the other applications.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Sounds like it can't handle HiDPI screens. Check if there's an update.

Comment: @Tetsujin - I actually uninstalled and re-installed VS. I am a brand new Mac user so I do not understand what you mean.

Comment: HiDPI is actually the 'windows' term for Retina. The app needs to be fully aware that it's running on a retina-type screen. Something from 2017 *ought* to be, as they've been around a while, but Microsoft has been pretty slow to come around to the idea. It's still my prime suspect.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, this is a known issue that happens not only on VS 2017 but it seems that on VS 2019 as well.

Among recommended solutions, expanding the VS window to full screen and back fixed the issue for me but some users report that it did not work for them.

The full thread can be found [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/406628/cursor-is-placed-on-line-below-where-mouse-is-clic.html)